# Resigned from my role and being replaced by a more senior post

Tags: resignation

I recently resigned from my role so the company I work for are in the process of advertising for my replacement. However, now the advert is live I note that they are recruiting someone in to that role as a "senior" at a significantly higher salary. They are also recruiting a junior to come in and pick up some of the other responsibilities I was carrying out.

Am I right to feel aggrieved? The senior job description describes my current role so if it's a senior post for them, is it not a senior post for me now? Also, is recruiting an additional role admission from my company that I had too much on?

I'd appreciate your thoughts on this.

---

I appreciate your answers all - consider this me officially backing down.

I've resigned for personal reasons rather than a feeling that I was deserving of a more senior position. It was more my surprise to see that they were replacing one role with two, one of which was at a higher scale yet carrying out exactly the same tasks (according to the JD). To your point Marv, if it was welcome to the company then I have certainly never been given any feedback to support that position, it has always been quite the opposite.

This isn't to say I'm arguing any of the points made though and I'd disagree that I was ranting.

Comment: Voting to close. This question is about a specific person's opinions/feelings, and is off-topic.

Comment: You quit, this means the company have the opportunity to re-arrange things to suit both themselves and the current job market better. The fact that they are hiring both a Senior and Junior suggests that they intend to split your role in two and expand both roles.... so no, nothing to be aggrieved about.

Comment: @KentAnderson  _Rant_ is the word you're looking for  :)

Comment: If it was other way around, would you feel the same? As in, they defined your job as entry level, with half the pay?

Comment: I think that situation would be more confusing to me Dan and I would be questioning it for other reasons. Obviously that is completely hypothetical and highly unlikely though whereas the situation I describe is what's actually happened.

Comment: If you left the position and upon your leaving they decided that your duties were worth much more than you were earning, then the only person you have to blame is yourself. If you feel you are undervalued wherever you are then the responsibility is on you to negotiate for more. To expect them one day to come up to you and say `Oh, we noticed you aren't making market salary... Let's just bump that up shall we?' is ridiculous.

Comment: Until shortly your company had no reason to reevaluate the situation in terms of seniority and salary. A company has no incentive to bump your salary 20%, and rarely does for current employees (which is why switching companies at some stage is a good career move). You leaving disturbed the status quo, and lead the companies reevaluation of the situation.

Comment: I would propose that this question be taken off hold as potentially useful and meeting the guidelines. The first question ("Am I right to feel aggrieved?") could be reframed as "Is such company practice considered fair from the standpoint of compensation for the outgoing position?" The second question may be addressed from the standpoint of how to describe the job on the CV when the job tasks do not match 'lower level' original position description. The last question may be reframed as whether the workload associated with the position from which the OP resigned was appropriate for his title.

Comment: @Aymor you can suggest edits (or make them, once above 2000 reputation) - this is a great way to help get a question better on topic.

Comment: @enderland I thought I suggested them above?

Answer (score 6):

You declared your position on working for the company when you submitted your resignation; why would you care what the company does in the future?

Suppose the answer is "yes the company clearly recognise now that you had too much work on"- to put it bluntly, so what? You chose (presumably) to leave rather than tackle any issues you perceived about workload or remuneration. I can see why it would be irritating for you and perhaps you feel you were "right all along", but that's life.

You should also consider that possibly you leaving the role was welcome to them (for reasons only they know) or perhaps that it has caused them to review the role and decided to grow it in the future into a more senior role (thus requiring more senior candidates). There are potentially many reasons for the change, none of which are really any business of yours now you have unilaterally withdrawn your support by resigning.

Also note that such change is often the catalyst for review, sometimes with the surprising results that would have modified or removed the very reasons for the initial change. Like when you split up with a partner because of their ingrained foibles, only to find they changed for a new partner and annoyingly stopped the very idiosyncrasies that caused you to split up with them!

Answer (score 3):

> Am I right to feel aggrieved?

It is human to feel aggrieved, but the fact is that you have not been treated unfair.

> The senior job description describes my current role so if it's a
>   senior post for them, is it not a senior post for me now?

**No**, it is not. The role you had in the company would be the one, which should go into your resume, and not the updated one *after your resignation*.

> They are also recruiting a junior to come in and pick up some of the
>   other responsibilities I was carrying out.

It is very common for companies to pick out people who are performing exceptionally, and offer them much senior positions. So, I don't feel this would be an insult to you or your role, and in no way would I feel that the junior is undeserving. (If the management picked him, then he must be good)

Note: If you thought you deserve a better compensation and a better role, you could have talked with your manager before resigning and convince him on the hike.

But now as you have left the company, even considering the company's moves as fair/unfair is irrelevant now.

Comment: +1 I agree, if the OP didn't negotiate with their manager then the lesson learnt is that if you wanted what they are now looking for you should of at least asked. on the other hand if the OP did ask and was refused then either the company didn't feel the OP deserved the title and raise or they've realised they lost a good employee and have resolved to mitigate that in future with improved terms.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I right to feel aggrieved? The senior job description describes my
>   current role so if it's a senior post for them, is it not a senior
>   post for me now? Also, is recruiting an additional role admission from
>   my company that I had too much on?

You can feel however you choose to feel. But you have not actually been aggrieved. You resigned.

The company can choose to describe the position any way it chooses. It can re-define the role as more senior. It can increase the responsibilities or reduce the responsibilities. It can increase the pay significantly, or reduce the pay.

It is not "a senior post for me now", since you don't have a post - you resigned.

Recruiting an additional junior person is not an admission of anything. As often happens, when someone leaves, the company is just deciding to do things differently.

Comment: And some of this may have been in the works before you resigned but you didn't know because they didn't want to get your hopes up before it was official.